# Atomikos JTA Transaction Manager 'Purging orphaned entry from log' logs in output

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, activemq-classic, jta, atomikos

I am using Atomikos Transaction Manager to manage distributed Transactions in a Spring-Boot standalone app to integrate ActiveMQ queues and a postgresql DB (JPA via Hibernate5), using Apache Camel.
My issue is that there are lots of  messages like the below printed in my logs.

`Purging orphaned entry from log: CoordinatorLogEntry [id=myapp148991647253713828, wasCommitted=true, state=COMMITTING]`

1. Why are these logs printed all the time?
2. I believe that the timeouts (ActiveMQ Component, Datasource or Atomikos) are not well configured, but I don't know how to start looking into it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide your configuration please ?

Comment: Hi Victor, thnx for your reply. I had totally forgotten about my question. I had found the answer on my own.  I posted my findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was really simple really. 
When messing with the configuration I mistakenly enabled the `com.atomikos.icatch.forget_orphaned_log_entries_delay` and changed the default value of `86400000 (1 day)` to `30000 (30 sec)`. For now, I just rolled back to default value.